# How to remove certain rows of a dataframe based on there being similar rows in the dataframe (strings)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with rows named like:

```
rp021047.tot
rp021048.tot
rp021048.L00
rp021048.L01
rp021048.tot
rp021049.tot
rp021050.tot
rp022047.tot
rp022048.tot
rp022049.tot
rp022050.tot
```

The point of main interest here are the lines:

```
rp021048.L00
rp021048.L01
rp021048.tot
```

These rows have exactly the same name except after the point. For duplicates like this, I wish to only keep the files with a `.L*` ending, deleting the `.tot` rows.

I am struggling to think of a way of doing this. I would really appreciate any ideas people may have. Thank you

Comment: `rp021048.tot` does not have `.L*`, why is it in the output?

Comment: .L* and .tot are both outputs. Some of my data only have a .tot file which is fine. If on the other hand, it has .L* files, I wish to delete the .tot file for that output.

Comment: But for non-duplicate rows like `rp021049.tot`, should the output contain `X.tot`? Why not cut down your sample input to 6 lines and post us the corresponding output?

Comment: Some answers are assuming the `.L00, .L01` come first in the listing and drop the last duplicate (assuming it's `.tot`), is that safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your filenames and then check `duplicated` with a condition

---

```
u = s.str.rsplit('.', 1, expand=True)
m = u.duplicated(0) & u[1].eq('tot')

s[~m]
```

```
0     rp021047.tot
1     rp021048.tot
2     rp021048.L00
3     rp021048.L01
5     rp021049.tot
6     rp021050.tot
7     rp022047.tot
8     rp022048.tot
9     rp022049.tot
10    rp022050.tot
dtype: object
```

---

Here, row `4` is removed, as it is a duplicate filename but has the `tot` extension.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. As an extra point if this was a single column of a data frame with around 40 columns, how would you append the original dataframe?

Comment: You can still index the original dataframe with the mask from above, just do `df[~m]`

Comment: This assumes the `.L00, .L01` come first and drops the last duplicate (assuming it's `.tot`), is that safe?

Answer (score 2):

You need to split with `.` and then grab the rows that starts with `L`.

```
outpt.loc[outpt.str.split('.').str[1].str.startswith('L')]
```

Output:

```
2    rp021048.L00
3    rp021048.L01
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to filter, here is my suggestion/ or solution. Let me know if this works. I tried it and it works for me.

'''

```
 data =['rp021047.tot', 'rp021048.tot', 'rp021048.L00','rp021048.L01',
'rp021048.tot', 'rp021049.tot', 'rp021050.tot','rp022047.tot',
'rp022048.tot','rp022049.tot','rp022050.tot']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns =['col1']
df1 = df[(df.col1.str.contains('L'))]
df1
```

'''

Output

```
    col1
2   rp021048.L00
3   rp021048.L01
```

Comment: @Allentro, could you please accept or reject or vote the solution I provided.